# Changing internal database version

Tags: sql-server

I want to know how I can create a database in SSMS 19 and it can be used in earliers versions.
This is the error Visual Studio gives me:

[image: Error]

I should have a database which internal database version would be 895 or higher.

Comment: What is it about the error message that's not clear? Sql Server database versions are not backward-compatible.

Comment: Hi @stu This message appear when I want to add a database archive to my project. I know it is not backward-compatible, so I want to create a database in an older version, but I can't find the option to change it.

Comment: What you are asking you cannot do. you cannot create a database in SqlServer 2019 that  "is" an older version. You need that database version installed. [https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2810/how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-a-lower-version/](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2810/how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-a-lower-version/)

Comment: SSMS <> SQL Server, SSMS is just a client app. There is no SSMS 19 nor is there SQL Server 19. I presume you mean SQL Server 2019.

Comment: @charlieface i mean i need a database compatible with sql server 2014 for example and the internal database version must be 800. I use ssms 19 to create databases

Comment: You cannot create a database in `SQL Server 2019` and then to use it in `SQL Server 2014`. It is not supported.

Comment: ["SSMS 18.8 is the latest general availability (GA) version of SSMS"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) And the version of SSMS is entirely irrelevant to the question